# Transforming XML into HTML5

Tags: xml, html, xslt

I have transformed a xml  file into HTML5 using XSLT but the questions is, where does it says this is now a HTML5 file?. I used browser inspectors but I can only see html. What I mean is, how can I be sure the transformation has successfully worked? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT will transform your XML into an HTML DOM. It doesn't change your source file; this transformation happens on-the-fly as the browser loads and renders the XML.

This HTML DOM can be observed using your browser's DOM inspector. In my browser (Firefox), it looks like this (line breaks and indentation added for clarity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>List of Movies.</title>
    <link href="movies.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="movies">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>Title</th><th>Year</th><th>Rank</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Pi</td><td>1998</td><td>7.1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Apollo 13</td><td>1995</td><td>7.5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Aliens</td><td>1986</td><td>8.2</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, is the given page correctly transformed?

Comment: @user3545850: Since this is your document, what constitutes "correctly transformed" depends on you. If you're asking whether the markup that's generated is valid, it seems valid to me.